# Git has stop working on windows 10 (git version 2.7.0 and git version 2.6.x)

Tags: git, windows-10, crash-reports

I don't know the reason why git is stop working on windows 10, I'd upgraded my windows from 8.1 to 10 few months ago, and now I had new project and I realized that git is always crash on windows 10 when I try git in command prompt and also not working when I try git clone on GUI version.

So I take my error picture to show you. I need your help!!!

[image: Git crashes on windows 10 while using git clone on command prompt]

Comment: You still have your git repository in the title bar of the command line

Comment: have you tried reinstalling git?

Comment: use WER to capture a crash dump (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx), create a support case and add the dmp to it, so that the devs can debug it

Comment: @Ferrybig. Yes I'd re-install in several times in the same version and older version but it still not working when I use "git clone" in both gui version and command line version.

Comment: I started having the same problem today. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I also got the same problem, git just fails to start. Happened after the latest windows 10 release preview update.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect if you are in the Windows 10 Insider program the most recent update Build 14251.rs1 may be the common issue here.  I have two machines on an that build and both have started experiencing git.exe startup fails.  I also have another Windows 10 machine that is on the RTM  (public) version and it is not experiencing an issue.  So, the best answer if you are using git and Windows 10 Build 14251 is to revert back to the official release RTM version of Windows 10 for now.

Comment: 04 feb 2016 : build 14257 has been released which to quote "The issue of periodic app crashes or other memory related app errors due to a memory management change has been resolved. If you were having issues launching the Git client for Windows, you should now be able to launch it in this build. " so should fix this issue, installing as i type...

Think i will dropping to the slow ring if this build works