# Git crashing on Windows 10 when cloning heroku git file

Tags: windows, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I've been following all of the directions on how to set up Heroku on Windows to create PHP web apps with. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#prepare-the-app

So I'm stuck on the "Preparing the app" stage, where I'm supposed to execute the following operation in terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/heroku/php-getting-started.git
cd php-getting-started
```

However, when I type in the first "clone" function, Git crashes, as evidenced in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RWXU.jpg)

I've restarted but to no avail. It does this every single time I execute the function in terminal. How do I remedy this, so that, in short, the cloning function works?

Somebody talked about a duplicate. [Git has stop working on windows 10 (git version 2.7.0 and git version 2.6.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744606/git-has-stop-working-on-windows-10-git-version-2-7-0-and-git-version-2-6-x) Issue is not the same. I am not using the windows 10 insider edition, so the solution is irrelevant, correct me if I'm wrong. Additionally, the question shows the crash occurring earlier in the process. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git has stop working on windows 10 (git version 2.7.0 and git version 2.6.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744606/git-has-stop-working-on-windows-10-git-version-2-7-0-and-git-version-2-6-x)

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: Troubleshoot the problem: First, try to clone another repo and see if it crashes so you can know where to start solving from, next check the version of your git to ensure its the latest

Comment: I tried to clone another .git and it didn't work. I'll try reinstalling Git.

Comment: Reinstalled; tried in git bash, works!